# Changing query to avoid "Aggregations of aggregations are not allowed" in Bigquery

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

Given user and order tables, I need to count users who made their first order on the next day after registration date.

I managed to list such users with the following query:

```
SELECT 
  users.first_name as first_name,
  users.last_name as last_name,
  users.registration_date as registration_date,
  min(orders.order_date) as first_order_date
FROM `users_table` as users
  JOIN `orders_table` as orders
  ON users.id = orders.user_id
GROUP BY
  first_name,
  last_name,
  registration_date
HAVING
  date_diff(first_order_date, registration_date, DAY) = 1
ORDER BY
  registration_date ASC
LIMIT 5
```

Resulting in:

```
+------------+-----------+-------------------+------------------+
| first_name | last_name | registration_date | first_order_date |
+------------+-----------+-------------------+------------------+
| Albert     | Ellis     | 2013-04-11        | 2013-04-12       |
| Charles    | Moore     | 2014-04-29        | 2014-04-30       |
| Jimmy      | Payne     | 2014-07-01        | 2014-07-02       |
| Angela     | Stanley   | 2014-10-21        | 2014-10-22       |
| Marie      | Bishop    | 2014-11-15        | 2014-11-16       |
+------------+-----------+-------------------+------------------+
```

Now, I can't wrap my head around counting them. When I try something like:

```
SELECT 
  count(date_diff(min(orders.order_date), users.registration_date, DAY) = 1)
FROM `users_table` as users
  JOIN `orders_table` as orders
  ON users.id = orders.user_id
```

I receive "Aggregations of aggregations are not allowed" error. How do I amend query to resolve that?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Below is for BigQuery Standard SQL

```
#standardSQL
SELECT COUNT(1) next_day_order_users
FROM `project.dataset.users_table` AS users
JOIN (
  SELECT user_id, MIN(order_date) first_order_date 
  FROM `project.dataset.orders_table`
  GROUP BY user_id
) AS orders
ON users.id = orders.user_id
WHERE DATE_DIFF(first_order_date, registration_date, DAY) = 1
```

Comment: I understand this is against SO comment rules, but I'm very grateful for all your fantastic responses on SO. This is excellent.

Answer (score 2):

Just put your query into subquery. You are already choosing clients who ordered next day after registration. So answer is a number of rows in your query

```
select count(1)
from ( SELECT 
  users.first_name as first_name,
  users.last_name as last_name,
  users.registration_date as registration_date,
  min(orders.order_date) as first_order_date
FROM `users_table` as users
  JOIN `orders_table` as orders
  ON users.id = orders.user_id
GROUP BY
  first_name,
  last_name,
  registration_date
HAVING
  date_diff(first_order_date, registration_date, DAY) = 1 ) x
```

Comment: That worked, thank you. Are nested SELECTs a common practice? Or there might be more elegant solution here?

Comment: It's very common practice. Of course there are different solutions to your problem, one of them is nested table

Answer (score 0):

Why not just use a `JOIN` condition?

```
SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT u.id)
FROM `users_table` u JOIN
     `orders_table` o        
     ON u.id = o.user_id AND
        date_diff(o.order_date, u.registration_date, DAY) = 1;
```

The `COUNT(DISTINCT` accounts for the fact that users could have multiple orders in one day.

Comment: User's got several orders with different dates. I need the date of first order for comparison. When trying "date_diff(min(orders.order_date), users.registration_date, DAY)" I receive "Aggregate function MIN not allowed in JOIN ON clause".

Comment: Is it possible for a user to make an order *before* that date?

Comment: There are several orders per user. E.g. user had registered on November 1st and made 3 orders on November 2nd, November 5th and November 21st. I need to count ones, who made their *first* order right on the *next day* after registration. They can't make orders before registration.